# Is my VPN leaking or is this normal?

Tags: network, privacy, vpn, openvpn

Hi when I am not connected to my VPN and do a `route print` I get one `0.0.0.0` entry in the `Network Destination` column. It has a gateway of `192....`.

When I connect to my VPN and do a `route print` I get two `0.0.0.0` entries in the `Network Destination` column. The first has a gateway of `192....`, the same as above. The second has a gateway of `10....` which I'm assuming is my VPN gateway.

When I run a `tracert` to a website the I see the `10....` ip address followed by addresses in the VPN server I'm connecting to. All tests I have run online show only my VPN information. I cannot see my ip in any of the above steps.

What concerns me is that I see `0.0.0.0` and `192....` on both `route print's` whether I'm connected to VPN or not.

**Is this normal behaviour or is my VPN leaking traffic?**

I have seen people say to delete the route but that would force me to be connected to my VPN all the time which I don't want.

Any help??

Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

**This is normal.** See the last column `Metric`. If there are two routes to the same destination, the one with lower `Metric` value has less cost and is chosen as the better alternative. On the other hand, the VPN tunnel itself needs a route to `0.0.0.0`, too.

Some (Open)VPN implementations do extra measurements to be chosen over any other connections. They split the `0.0.0.0` e.g. into two halves in addition to using low metric values. As this route is more specific, it gets chosen over `0.0.0.0`.

```
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.254    192.168.1.100     35
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0         10.8.0.1         10.8.0.5      3
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0         10.8.0.1         10.8.0.5      3
```

Likewise, you still see more specific routes e.g. for your physical networks:

```
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.100    291
```

That's because OpenVPN's `redirect-gateway` doesn't actively remove routes to local networks, whereas some other *full tunneling* implementations go further by doing it. From the [Reference manual for OpenVPN 2.4](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/):

> `–redirect-gateway flags…`
>
> Automatically execute routing commands to cause all outgoing IP
>   traffic to be redirected over the VPN. This is a client-side
>   option.This option performs three steps:
>
> 1. Create a static route for the –remote address which forwards to
>      the pre-existing default gateway. This is done so that (3) will not
>      create a routing loop.
> 2. Delete the default gateway route.
> 3. Set the new default gateway to be the VPN endpoint address
>      (derived either from –route-gateway or the second parameter to
>      –ifconfig when –dev tun is specified).

There you could leak information through various protocols e.g. mDNS, LLMNR, NetBIOS or SSDP, but that's another story and doesn't affect the connections to the Internet through the VPN.

Comment: Is this an example of split tunnelling as opposed to full tunnel type VPN where all traffic must go through the VPN concentrator?

Comment: I've added some details regarding that. Technically speaking, OpenVPN in full tunneling mode is still a split tunnel, because it allows connections to local networks. From this perspective, split tunnel is one that doesn't add `0.0.0.0` routes at all, but only specific routes e.g. to a corporate network.